# How to remove single quotes from array of strings and comma separate them into new array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a array of elements with single quotes and I want to remove the single quotes and separate them into new values for each ip and store as strings in another array using javascript.

```
 let myArray = [ '10.202.10.800,10.202.10.801,10.202.10.802',
      '10.202.10.803,10.202.10.804,10.202.10.805',
      '10.202.10.806,10.202.10.807,10.202.10.808']
```

I want new array output like this

```
newArray = [ '10.202.10.800','10.202.10.801','10.202.10.802',
  '10.202.10.803','10.202.10.804','10.202.10.805',
  '10.202.10.806','10.202.10.807','10.202.10.808']
```

I have tried, parse, toString and other methods but couldn't achieve this.

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid syntax, it has to be an array of strings.

Comment: yes, i need them as array of strings ! edited the question Phix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by looping through each value in your array, splitting them based on the commas.  This will return an array of arrays.  Then, we can flatten our multi-dimensional array using concat.apply.

```
let myArray = [ '10.202.10.800,10.202.10.801,10.202.10.802',
      '10.202.10.803,10.202.10.804,10.202.10.805',
      '10.202.10.806,10.202.10.807,10.202.10.808'];

let myMidArray = myArray.map((string) => {
  return string.split(",");
});

let myMergedArray = [].concat.apply([], myMidArray);

console.log(myMergedArray);
```

Let me know if you'd like me to explain in greater detail any of these methods if you're not familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split and collect.

```js
let myArray = [ '10.202.10.800,10.202.10.801,10.202.10.802',
      '10.202.10.803,10.202.10.804,10.202.10.805',
      '10.202.10.806,10.202.10.807,10.202.10.808']
      
const newArray = myArray.flatMap(str => str.split(','))

console.info(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this method, you can go through each array index, split the string then concat that result into a new array.

```
let myArray = [ '10.202.10.800,10.202.10.801,10.202.10.802',
      '10.202.10.803,10.202.10.804,10.202.10.805',
      '10.202.10.806,10.202.10.807,10.202.10.808'];
let outArray= [];

for ( let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ){
    outArray = outArray.concat(myArray[i].split(','));
}
console.log(outArray);
```